# Re-assigning methods in Go

Tags: go

Suppose I have the following:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type I1 interface {
    m1()
}

func f1() {
    fmt.Println("dosomething")
}

func main() {
    var obj I1
    obj.m1 = f1

    obj.m1()
}
```

This generates the error

```
./empty.go:16: cannot assign to obj.m1
```

Why can't I assign to 'method fields'?

In C, I can just pass around function pointers. What is the equivalent in Go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign a function to an interface, you can do it for a struct, for example:

```
type S1 struct {
    m1 func()
}

func f1() {
    fmt.Println("dosomething")
}

func main() {
    var obj S1
    obj.m1 = f1

    obj.m1()
}
```

// another example

```
type I1 interface {
    m1()
}

type S1 struct {}

func (S1) m1() {
    fmt.Println("dosomething")
}

type S2 struct { S1 }

func (s S2) m1() {
    fmt.Println("dosomething-2")
    //s.S1.m1() //uncomment to call the original m1.
}

func doI1(i I1) {
    i.m1()
}

func main() {
    doI1(S1{})
    doI1(S2{S1{}})
}
```

[<kbd>play</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/iPF7ZhEuvV)

Comment: the question is about RE-assigning.

Comment: @captaincurrie you can't, you can "shadow" it, I'll add an example.

Comment: hey that worked! What is this signature `m1 func()`?

Comment: @captaincurrie you can assign functions to variables (like C's function pointers), that's the syntax for it `variableName func(arguments...) returnType`

Comment: Thanks! Funny, i havn't seen that syntax in all the documentation i've read. I've only seen what i wrote in my example. What exactly did i do wrong?

Comment: @captaincurrie for starters you can't "reassign" an already assigned function, you can only assign a function pointer. and you were trying to assign a value to an interface. I recommend going through http://tip.golang.org/doc/effective_go.html carefully.